# Find number of replacements when using a global Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a sentence (string) containing words. I want to replace all occurrences of a word with another. I use `newString = oldString.replace(/w1/gi, w2);`, but now I need to report to the user how many words I actually replaced.

Is there a quick way to do it without resorting to:

1. Replacing one word at a time and counting.
2. Comparing `oldString` to `newString` word-by-word and tallying the differences?
   (The easy case is if oldString === newString => 0 replacements, but beyond that, I'll have to run over both and compare).

Is there any RegEx "trickery" I can use here, or should I just avoid using the `g` flag?

Comment: Use a callback `var cnt=0; var res = s.replace(/str/g, function($0) { cnt++; return 'newstr';});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Option 1: Using the `replace` callback

By using the callback, you can increment a counter, and then return the new word in the callback, this allows you to traverse the string only 1 time, and achieve a count.

```js
var string = 'Hello, hello, hello, this is so awesome';
var count = 0;
string = string.replace(/hello/gi, function() {
  count++;
  return 'hi';
});

console.log('New string:', string);
console.log('Words replaced', count);
```

## Option 2: Using `split` ***and*** `join`

Also using the split method, instead of using regex, just join with the new word to create the new string. This solution allows you to avoid using regex at all to achieve counts.

```js
var string = 'Hello, hello, hello, this is so awesome';

string = string.split(/hello/i);
var count = string.length - 1;
string = string.join('Hi');

console.log('New string:', string);
console.log('Words replaced', count);
```

Comment: Yes! The replace function parameter was what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string with the regex you're using and get the length.

```
oldString.split(/w1/gi).length - 1
```

Working example:

```
var string = "The is the of the and the";
var newString = string.replace(/the/gi, "hello");

var wordsReplaced = string.split(/the/gi).length - 1;

console.log("Words replaced: ", wordsReplaced);
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it would work! I'm hoping there's a more efficient way then re-traversing the original string though. If we can't find one - your answer will serve.